# SQL Nested Query with distinct count

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a dilemma, and I'm hoping someone will be able to help me out. I am attempting to work on some made up problems from an old text book of mine, this isn't a question from the book, but the data is, I just wanted to see if I could still work in SQL, so here goes. When this code is executed,

```
SELECT COUNT(code_description) "Number of Different Crimes", last, first, 
code_description 
FROM
(
SELECT criminal_id, last, first, crime_code, code_description
FROM criminals 
JOIN crimes USING (criminal_id)
JOIN crime_charges USING (crime_id)
JOIN crime_codes USING (crime_code)
ORDER BY criminal_id
)
WHERE criminal_id = 1020
GROUP BY last, first, code_description;
```

I am provided with these results:

```
Number of Different Crimes   LAST            FIRST      CODE_DESCRIPTION             
                     1       Phelps          Sam        Agg Assault                    
                     1       Phelps          Sam        Drug Offense
```

Inevitably, I would like the number of different crimes to be 2 for each line since this criminal has two unique crimes charged to him. I would like it to be displayed something like:

```
Number of Different Crimes   LAST            FIRST      CODE_DESCRIPTION             
                     2       Phelps          Sam        Agg Assault                    
                     2       Phelps          Sam        Drug Offense
```

Not to push my luck but I would also like to get rid of the follow line also:

```
WHERE criminal_id = 1020
```

to something a little more elegant to represent any criminal with more than 1 crime type associated with them, for this case, Sam Phelps is the only one in this data set.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, perhaps you can remove your `group by` clause, and instead use `count(code_description) over (partition by last, first)`?

Comment: Thank you for commenting @sgeddes! I attempted your method and received an error stating 'SQL command not properly ended'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sgeddes said in a comment, you can use an analytic count, which doesn't need a subquery if you're specifying the criminal ID:

```
SELECT COUNT(code_description) OVER (PARTITION BY first, last) AS "Number of Different Crimes",
  last, first, code_description 
FROM criminals 
JOIN crimes USING (criminal_id)
JOIN crime_charges USING (crime_id)
JOIN crime_codes USING (crime_code)
WHERE criminal_id = 1020;
```

If you want to look for anyone with multiple crimes then you do need a subquery so you can filter on the analytic result:

```
SELECT charge_count AS "Number of Different Crimes",
  last, first, code_description
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT code_description) OVER (PARTITION BY first, last) AS charge_count,
    criminal_id, last, first, code_description 
  FROM criminals 
  JOIN crimes USING (criminal_id)
  JOIN crime_charges USING (crime_id)
  JOIN crime_codes USING (crime_code)
)
WHERE charge_count > 1
ORDER BY criminal_id, code_description;
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73b7b/1).

If the charges are across multiple crimes, but duplicated, then the distinct count still works, but you might want to make add a distinct to the overall result set - unless you want to show other crime-specific info - otherwise you [get something like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ac34/2).

Comment: THANK YOU!! Your suggestion worked as instructed. I appreciate you taking the time to help me out! @Alex